# Loosing my "diff" value when using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I don't know what's happening, i have my algorithme which receive a 
`timestamp`, i'm comparing it with a moment.now() date. And then use the `diff` to assign the right day in a variable.

But, for an obscure reason, i'm loosing the diff value after the first `if`, i tried with an affected value and also by calling each time the `diff` function, but it is still buggy.

```js
var timS = {"1" :1499889780000, "2" : 1500339840000, "3" :1501081920000, "4" :1501323720000, "5" : 1532912460000 ,"6" : 1499889780000, "7": 1499954196000, "8" : 1500339840000, "9" :  1501081920000, "10" :  1501323720000, "11" :  1532912460000};

for(var i = 1; i < 12; i++)
{
 console.log("Day: " +testDate(timS[i], i));
}

function testDate(timeStamp, i) {

  var day = moment(timeStamp);
  var a = moment.now();
  var diffe = day.diff(a, 'days');
  
  console.log("Have my diff value here : "+diffe+" at step :"+i);
  
  var param;

  if (diffe < 7 && diffe > 0) 
  {
   return day.format('dddd');
  }
   if (diffe === 0) 
   {
      return day.format('[Today] dddd';
    }
  } else {
    var param2 = day.format('L');
    return param2;
  }
};
```

#### EDIT :

I have edited the snippet, what I'm trying to do is to return these values : Today and Tomorrow. To do that i'm testing the `diff`between now() and the timestamp. But, as @wildWolf pointed it, it appears that two timestamps can have the same diff because they are distant from less than 24 hours...

How can i return "Today" or "Tomorrow", and only these words (not Today with a long UTC date) ?

Comment: Provide a fiddle or plunker which reproduces the issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/oh9Leda2/#&togetherjs=7FMamD2Myk not sure it is really working, first time i'm using fiddle...

Comment: Your fiddle isn't working because the `timeStamp` parameter in your function is replacing the `timeStamp` variable you create originally. As a result, moment is creating a new time for `undefined`, which is the same value as `now`. Not sure if this is the problem in your real code...

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, what does your code should do? What is your issue? Please try to fix your snippet and/or your fiddle (remove `$scope` and add external resources like moment.js) in order to make it runnable. Moreover provide some input (`timeStamp`) samples with the expected result.

Comment: The fiddle is updated as my main post, hope I was more clear than the first time. Let me know if not. In the fiddle you will see into the console my issue, I got two `today`, for two different days, of course i'd prefer one `today`and one `tomorrow`: https://jsfiddle.net/xj9fdyu9/#&togetherjs=7FMamD2Myk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) with `day` granularity gives the difference in days, but two moments with `0` days differences could be not in the same day. For example:

```
moment().diff( moment().subtract(21, 'h'), 'd') // 0
moment().isSame( moment().subtract(21, 'h'), 'd') // false until 21
```

So I suggest to use [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) instead of `diff`, herea working sample:

```js
var timS = {"1" :1499889780000, "2" : 1500339840000, "3" :1501081920000, "4" :1501323720000, "5" : 1532912460000 ,"6" : 1499889780000, "7": 1499954196000, "8" : 1500339840000, "9" :  1501081920000, "10" :  1501323720000, "11" :  1532912460000};

for(var i = 1; i < 12; i++)
{
  console.log("Day: " +testDate(timS[i], i));
}

// TestDate is using into a loop, to parse all timeStamp
function testDate(timeStamp, i) {
  var day = moment(timeStamp);
  var now = moment();

  if( day.isSame(now, 'day') ){
    return day.format('[Today] dddd');
  } else if( day.isSame(now, 'week') ){
    return day.format('dddd');
  } else {
    return day.format('L');
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note that moment hase the [`calendar`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/) method to do something similar to what you need:

```js
var timS = {"1" :1499889780000, "2" : 1500339840000, "3" :1501081920000, "4" :1501323720000, "5" : 1532912460000 ,"6" : 1499889780000, "7": 1499954196000, "8" : 1500339840000, "9" :  1501081920000, "10" :  1501323720000, "11" :  1532912460000};

for(var i = 1; i < 12; i++)
{
  console.log("Day: " +testDate(timS[i], i));
}

// TestDate is using into a loop, to parse all timeStamp
function testDate(timeStamp, i) {
  var day = moment(timeStamp);
  var now = moment();
  
  return day.calendar(now, {
    sameDay: '[Today] dddd',
    nextDay: 'dddd',
    nextWeek: 'dddd',
    lastDay: 'dddd',
    lastWeek: 'dddd',
    sameElse: 'L'
  });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```